# Key name is not being accepted in postman

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I'm getting the error as name required even after providing the key value of the name in postman. I think I am making an error in the schema

```
app.post('/api/genres', (req, res)=>{
    const { error }= validateGenre(req.body)
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error)

    const genre = {
        id: genres.length +1,
        name: req.body.name
    }
    genres.push(genre)
    res.send(genre)
})

app.put('/api/genres/:id', (req,res) => {
    const genre = genres.find(c => c.id===parseInt(req.params.id))
    if(!genre) return res.status(404).send('Invalid ID')

    const { error }= validateGenre(req.body)
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)
    
    genre.name= req.body.name
    res.send(genre)
})

    // **I think I did something wrong here**
function validateGenre(genre) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().min(3).required()
    })
  
   return schema.validate(genre);
}
```

Comment: You can test the `validateGenre` function without running the entire server. Try this `console.log(validateGenre({ name 'Hello world' }));` Also try `console.log(typeof(req.body), req.body)` to make sure the body is an object and to see it has the name property.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're parsing the body. Assuming you're using JSON in both postman and your frontend, you should have the following:

```js
const jsonParser = require('body-parser').json({ extended: true });

// in order to use it on all routes.
app.use(jsonParser);

// or the more recommended way, add jsonParser only to the specific
// endpoints you want to parse JSON
app.post('/api/genres', jsonParser, (req, res)=>{
    const { error }= validateGenre(req.body)
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error)

    const genre = {
        id: genres.length +1,
        name: req.body.name
    }
    genres.push(genre)
    res.send(genre)
})
```

You should also log the body you receive and test it without spinning up the whole server as Molda suggested in their comment.